# Yii, Is it good MVC practice to echo in the controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

It seems like i am not following the MVC design structure.

I'm making an ajax call from  my view to a Controller function

Controller

```
public function actionGetClient()
 {
  $user =  Client::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$_POST['email'], 'password'=>$_POST['pass']));
  echo $user->fullname;
 }
```

View (the calling ajax)

```
       CHtml::ajaxLink(
            $text = 'get user',  
            $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('[my controller]/getClient'), 
            $ajax=array (        
            'type'=>'POST', 
             'data' => array('email'=>email, 'pass'=>pass),
            'beforeSend' => "function( request )
                      {
                           $(\".result\").html(\"fetching...\")
                      }", 
            'success'=>"function(data){  
                     $(\".result\").html(\"user is :\"+data)
                            }            
                      "        
            ));
```

Is it good to  "echo" the $user->fullname inside the controller for the ajax success function to display it? My boss doesn't like it when i print stuff in my  controller, how can i approach this

because when i use return instead, the ajax success gets a null value

```
return $user->fullname;
```

Comment: You could make a view that only outputs $user->fullname, and do return $this->partialRender('fullnameview.php') instead of the echo statement;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

It's not a good practice.

You need to create a view to use echo.

You can use `return $this->renderPartial('VIEW_NAME');` to render a view without Layout.

Answer (score 2):

You should write 'return' instead of 'echo'. 'echo' is not a good practice for ajax response. You don't need to make a new view for just return a name in your case.

```
public function actionGetClient()
{
   $user =  Client::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$_POST['email'],'password'=>$_POST['pass']));
   return $user->fullname;
}
```

Comment: this would still be taking a shortcut, you are not rendering a view and thus eliminating various debugging features that would otherwise be available to you

Comment: i have mentioned this on my question, if i use return, there is nothing to display on the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

No. A controller’s supposed to pass its results to a view for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid echoing in the controller what we usually do is have a ajax view folder and a json view and render with that so:

```
public function actionGetClient()
{
  $user =  Client::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        'email'=>$_POST['email'],
        'password'=>$_POST['pass']
   ));

   $this->render("json",array("outputData"=>$user));
 }
```

then add this to the controller as well:

```
public function getViewPath(){
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
        if(($module=$this->getModule())===null)
            $module=Yii::app();
        return $module->getViewPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."ajax";
    }
    return parent::getViewPath();
}
```

and in the ajax views folder add a json.php file like so

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// output data
echo json_encode($outputData);
```

please degug the code as I wrote it free hand. You can also set a marker in the controller like $viewPath and set it before the rendering

Comment: This is a very interesting answer..Can you explain the 2nd block of code, what do we need it for.

Comment: each controller searches by default in the views folder with the same name so for FooController if you render bar view it will kook for this file: views/foo/bar.php but we only what to have the json layout once so I overwrite the getView function so I can render this file: views/ajax/json.php form any controller I please. In praxis I used a marker for the viewpath decision instead of isAjaxRequest

Comment: also you have to choose the controller layout used

Comment: Thanks. Isn't this simpler to implement, cause it think it does the same


    $this.renderPartial('application.views.ajax.json')